# Activity Indicator View between table controllers - swift 2

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, swift2, uiactivityindicatorview

I have built a project has many `tableViewControllers` connected together, my project is based on parse so it's taking a long time before it is downloaded and appears.

In the main time I want `UIActivityIndicatorView` to appear as an alert until the `tableViewController` appears. 
I have found this code:

```
var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Please wait...", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: nil);


    var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 10, 37, 37)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
    loadingIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    alert.setValue(loadingIndicator, forKey: "accessoryView")
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    alert.show();
```

It's working fine but I have two problems:

1 - I can not stop it until click okay -> I want stop and hidden auto after appear data

2- it is starting and appearing after go in to the `tableviewcontroller` -> I want start before go

Answer (score 0):

When it is time for the alert to go away, use this:

```
alert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, animated: true)
```

Note that UIAlertView is deprecated for iOS 9

Comment: Thx for helping
i fix it by using thread & queue 

and also i use dismiss code with time for go automatically